# if else statement in shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement

I have this script that does different things depending on the parameters you put as the input:

```
        #!/bin/bash
cadena="ls -alis"
while [ $# -e 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        -p) [ $cadena = "$cadena | grep $2" ] ;;
        -o) [ if [ $2 = 'mida' ] then
                $cadena="$cadena -lS"
              elif [ $2 = 'inode' ] then
                $cadena="$cadena | sort -t 1" 
              fi
            ] ;;
        -d) [ if [ `expr substr $2 1 1`” = '/' ] then
                $cadena="$cadena $2"
              elif [ `expr substr $2 1 1`” != '/' ] then
                $cadena="$cadena `pwd`/$2" 
              fi
            ] ;;
        -s) [ $cadena="$cadena > $2" ] ;;
        shift 2
    esac
done
$cadena
```

Updated the code with `case`.
The error is the same one a the beginning, in the line 9 with the `elif [ $2 = 'inode' ] then` statement, it says incorrect token.

Comment: The second line is wrong: `[$# -e 0]` needs spaces around the brackets. In general, all `[ ]` need spaces around, so cross check it because I see more more.

Comment: You're right, I updated it but the error wasn't from there, any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently you want to store the output of `ls -alis` --> `cadena=$(ls -alis)`

Comment: I don't really need to save it, I just need to execute it. Edited the code.

Comment: If you do `cadena="ls -alis"` you are storing a string. If you want this command to be executed then you need to use `cadena=$(ls -alis)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't mix single bracket notation `[ ]` with `==`, it's `[ ... = ... ]` or `[[ ... == ... ]]`.
2. You don't need two `shift`s, you can `shift 2` instead (if this is really what you want).
3. You can replace the outer `if` with a switch for readability and avoid the nested `if` mess:

   ```
   case $1 in
       -p) [...] ;;
       -o) [...] ;;
       -d) [...] ;;
       -s) [...] ;;
       *)  [...] ;;
   esac
   ```
4. You will want to read [BashFAQ/050 aka I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I really like this format. I updated the code, however it still gives me errors that I cannot fix. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: You need two colons `;;` (this is the `shell` equivalent of a required `break` statement and your `if-elif` constructs need a closing `fi`. Ok, there is actually more wrong with your code...maybe you want to read a `bash` tutorial first? Or at least [BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).

Comment: Yeah... I guess I'll have to read that because I really don't understand what's wrong with the `elif` statement. I've looked up the web and I find it in this format. Thank anyway!

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you need a `fi` to close each of those inner `if` statements.

The first line of the script has spaces before the `#!`. If it really looks like that, then you might be picking up a different shell.

But the syntax error is caused by having the `then` on the same line as the `if`. The shell only recognizes reserved words at the beginning of a line or equivalent (e.g. after a semicolon). So you want:

```
if [ $2 = 'mida' ]
then
```

or

```
if [ $2 = 'mida' ]; then
```

Comment: I think it is fine there. But after `elif [ $2 == 'inode' ] then` he does need one `fi`, indeed.

Comment: I edited the code because after doing this and adding the `fi` at the end of every elif it still didn't work.