# Concatenating easy strings with shell going wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, ls

I'm trying to concatenate strings and then executing the resulting string but it doesn't work as it should, here's the code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    c="ls -alis"
    c="$c | grep me"
    echo $c
    $c
```

It prints `ls -alis | grep me` but it doesn't print the any file with the string 'me' in it, it gives me this error:

```
ls: |: No such file or directory
ls: grep: No such file or directory
ls: u1920477: No such file or directory
```

However, if I type `ls -alis | grep me` directly to the terminal it does show the files it should show me. Why is this happening?

Comment: As [I commented before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836510/if-else-statement-in-shell-script#comment34833285_22836510), you need `$()` to perform the command. So I guess you are looking for `c=$($c | grep "me")`.

Comment: You were right, it worked! However, if I try to do it with `sort -k 1` instead of grep, it doesn't. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to do `eval $c` here.  But I'd encourage you to avoid building commands out of strings like this--if you can find a better way it will probably be easier to understand and safer too.

Answer (score 1):

Strings hold data; shell functions hold code.

```
c () {
    ls -alis | grep me
}
```